# Laravel - moving file causing error

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to copy a file from one directory to another as follows:

```
$files = File::allFiles($temp);
                            foreach ($files as $f)
                            {
                                $f->move($destination, File::name($f));
                            }
```

I am getting this error:

Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo::move()

In the following line:
$f->move($destination, File::name($f));

It seems like it does not detect $f as being of type file because every time I try and use any of its functions like 
getClientOriginalName()

I get an error.

I keep getting that error. It seems as its not registering $f as being a file..

Also another thing to keep in mind is that I don't know the name of the file thus why I get all of the files in the directory (only ever 1 at a time)

Comment: what version of laravel are you using

Comment: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile this has the method move, not SpfFileInfo

Comment: I know but why is it using spfFileInfo? I don't get that. or even a better question, how do I change it to use that class.

Comment: Go into app.php and check the File alias what is it using ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the symfony finder component? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html. Apparently laravel is relying on it anyway, so why don't just use that? The example you're looking for is at the top of the page.

Comment: 'File'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',

Comment: By the way - what exactly is the purpose of your code? It sounds like you're trying to move an uploaded file?

Comment: so basicly you are getting the file with a different class and trying to call a method in a different class.

Comment: tftd, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you'll go throught function calls in this method - https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L285 - you will see that Finder creates directly SplFileInfo during iteration. I do not understand why do you expect UploadedFile in results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File::get($f)
```

Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
$files = File::allFiles($temp);
```

to

```
$files = Input::file('files');
```

Comment: Can't do that as I don't know the name of the file

Comment: you dont need to know the name of the file, you only need to know the posted name field from your form

Comment: problem is I'm using dropzone and it doesn't give me the name of it :)

Comment: open inspect element and check the name atribute value of the file html tag, then you can just use that.

Comment: sadly dropzone does not work this way, it uses javascript and jquery to do it, doesn't use the actual form.

Comment: just return Input::all() and you can see the posted name

Comment: Array ( [title] => afsadasdas [price] => 4 [description] => [type] => 0 [details] => [custom_email_message] => [aff_percent] => [secondary_aff_link] => [display] => 1 [_token] => 1bPi6qrlXHlB0lcTMjnFZgPNXSHkroQaeQ8UK3wb ) 1

Comment: As you can see no name of the file there :/ I just need to know how to move an existing file from x to y in laravel to be honest.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually posting the file ?

Comment: Yes the file is already there, I did a work around this, I used copy directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$files = File::files($temp);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    File::move($file, $destination . basename($file));
    // [or]
    // rename($file, $destination . basename($file));
}
```